# How to do animation close as same as open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

while click on (?), have opened options with animation effect. Animation is working fine. Want to close the options same as open animation which is options bubble effect, but close animation effect is not same like as open animation. Need closing animation is also same as bubble effect.

Can anyone help me to find the mistake what i did. Thanks.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var $body = jQuery('body');
    var $cs_fixed_wrapper = jQuery('.cs_fixed_wrapper');

    // customer service icon click - ex. (?) click
    jQuery('img.cs_trigger_icon').on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();

        if(jQuery('.cs_options').hasClass('slide_open')) {
            jQuery('.cs_options').removeClass('slide_open').addClass('slide_close');
        }
        else {
            jQuery('.cs_options').removeClass('slide_close').addClass('slide_open');
        }
    });

    var clickEvent = {};
    // cs options - trigger functionalities
    $body.on('click', '.cs_action_trigger', function(ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();

        var window_width = jQuery(window).width();
        var data_type = jQuery(this).data('type');

        if(window_width < 800) {
            if(!clickEvent[data_type]) {
                clickEvent = {};
                clickEvent[data_type] = 1;

                if(data_type == 'contact') {
                    jQuery('.cs_contact').addClass('cs_contact_opened');
                }
                else if(data_type == 'supportarticle') {
                    jQuery('.cs_supportarticle').addClass("cs_supportarticle_opened");
                    return false;
                }
                else if(data-type == 'cs_faq') {
                    jQuery('.cs_faq').addClass("cs_faq_opened");
                }
            } else if (clickEvent[data_type]) {
                clickEvent = {};
                clickEvent[data_type] = 1;

                if(data_type == 'contact') {
                    jQuery('.cs_contact_modal').addClass('opened');
                    $body.addClass('cs_popup_opened');
                    jQuery('.close').fadeOut('200');

                    clickEvent = {};
                }
                else if(data_type == 'tutorial') {
                    jQuery('.cs_tutorial_modal').addClass('opened');
                    $body.addClass('cs_popup_opened');
                    jQuery('.close').fadeOut('200');

                    clickEvent = {};
                }
                else if(data_type == 'supportarticle') {
                    clickEvent = {};
                }
                else if(data_type == 'cs_faq') {
                    jQuery('.cs_faq_modal').addClass('opened');
                    $body.addClass('cs_popup_opened');
                    jQuery('.close').fadeOut('200');

                    clickEvent = {};
                }
            }

        } else {
            if(data_type == 'contact') {
                jQuery('.cs_contact_modal').addClass('opened');
    $body.addClass('cs_popup_opened');
    
                jQuery('.cs_contact_modal .close_btn').fadeIn();
            }
            else if(data_type == 'supportarticle') {
                // console.log(data_type);
            }
            else if(data_type == 'cs_faq') {
                jQuery('.cs_faq_modal').addClass('opened');
    $body.addClass('cs_popup_opened');
    
                jQuery('.cs_faq_modal .close_btn').fadeIn();
            }
        }
    });
    

    // customer service - contact form popup outside close for desktop
    jQuery('.cs_contact_modal').on('click', function(ev) {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('opened');
        $body.removeClass('cs_popup_opened');

        // show close icon on multiple popups
        show_close_icon();

        // body scroll based on condition
        body_scroll_for_custom_pages();

        contact_form_cf7_empty();

    });

    jQuery('.cs_contact_modal .modal_profile_wrapper').on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });

    // customer service - contact form popup close for desktop
    jQuery('.cs_contact_modal_close').on('click', function(ev) {
        jQuery('.cs_contact_modal').removeClass('opened');
        $body.removeClass('cs_popup_opened');

        // show close icon on multiple popups
        show_close_icon();

        // body scroll based on condition
        body_scroll_for_custom_pages();
        jQuery('.cs_contact').removeClass('cs_contact_opened');
        contact_form_cf7_empty();
    });


    // outside click to close the customer service slide options
    jQuery('body').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('.cs_options').removeClass('slide_open').addClass('slide_close');
    });

});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.cs_fixed_wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 99999999;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.cs_inner_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column-reverse;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.cs_action_trigger.cs_contact_opened {
    width: 144px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
.slide_open .cs_action_trigger.cs_contact_opened {
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.slide_open .cs_action_trigger.cs_contact_closed {
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.cs_supportarticle {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.cs_action_trigger.cs_supportarticle_opened {
    width: 188px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
.slide_open .cs_action_trigger.cs_supportarticle_opened,
.slide_open .cs_action_trigger.cs_supportarticle_closed {
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.cs_faq {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.slide_open .cs_action_trigger.cs_faq_opened {
    width: 102px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
.slide_open .cs_action_trigger.cs_faq_opened,
.slide_open .cs_action_trigger.cs_faq_closed {
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.cs_support_wrapper > img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cs_options {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    align-items: flex-end;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .7s;
}
.cs_options.slide_open {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: transform .2s;
}
.cs_options.slide_close {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: transform 0.4s, visibility .4s, opacity .6s;
}
.cs_contact_icon img,
.cs_supportarticle_icon img,
.cs_faq img {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.cs_supportarticle_opened .cs_supportarticle_icon img {
    left: -59px;
}
.cs_contact_opened .cs_contact_icon img {
    left: -40px;
}
.cs_faq_opened .cs_faq_icon img {
    left: -18px;
}
.slide_open .cs_action_trigger .circle {
    animation: bubble .7s 0.5;
}
.slide_close .cs_action_trigger .circle {
    transition: all 1s;
}
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.cs_faq .circle {
    background: #ff422d;
}
.cs_supportarticle .circle {
    background: #00b44a;
}
.cs_contact .circle {
    background: #00387c;
}
.cs_action_trigger {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: normal;
    font-size: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    transform: scale(.5);
    transition: transform .5s, top 0.4s;
    position: relative;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.cs_action_trigger:nth-child(1) {
    top: 60px;
}
.cs_action_trigger:nth-child(2) {
    top: 120px;
}
.cs_action_trigger:nth-child(3) {
    top: 180px;
}
.slide_open .cs_action_trigger {
    transform: scale(1);
    top: 0px;
    transition: transform .5s, top .3s;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.cs_action_trigger img {
    width: 28px;
    position: relative;
    transition: left 0.3s;
}
.cs_contact img {
    top: 6px;
    left: 0px;
}
.cs_supportarticle img {
    top: 7px;
    left: 0px;
}
.cs_faq img {
    top: 4px;
    left: 0px;
}
@keyframes bubble{
    0%  {transform: scale(0,0)      translateY(0); }
    10%  { transform: scale(0.5,0.5)   translateY(0); }
    30%  { transform: scale(1.1,1.1)   translateY(-20px); }
    50%  { transform: scale(1.05,1.05) translateY(0); }
    57%  { transform: scale(1,1)      translateY(-7px); }
    64%  { transform: scale(1,1)      translateY(0); }
    100% { transform: scale(1,1)      translateY(0); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cs_fixed_wrapper">
        <div class="cs_inner_wrapper">
            <div class="cs_support_wrapper">
                <div class="cs_options slide_close">
                        <div class="cs_contact cs_action_trigger" data-link="cs_contact_popup" data-type='contact'>
                            <span class="circle"></span>
                            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WusFO.png" alt="C"/>
                            <span class="cs_content cs_link_content">Contact Us</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cs_supportarticle cs_action_trigger" data-type='supportarticle'>
                            <a href="">
                                <span class="circle"></span>
                                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzkHq.png" alt="S"/>
                                <span class="cs_content cs_link_content">Support Articles</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cs_faq cs_action_trigger" data-link="cs_faq_popup" data-type='cs_faq'>
                            <span class="circle"></span>
                            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEzHb.png" alt="F"/>
                            <span class="cs_content cs_link_content">FAQ</span>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <img class="cs_trigger_icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNQUZ.png" alt="C"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i see it fine... https://www.screencast.com/t/ataNVbuixMV

Comment: You mean you want to play the animation in reverse?

Comment: yes, want same animation in reverse - @yunzen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another set of keyframes say 'unbubble' and do the exact opposite transitions.

```
@keyframes unbubble{
    0%  {transform: scale(1,1)      translateY(-10px); }
    30%  { transform: scale(1.1,1.1)      translateY(-15px); }
    50%  { transform: scale(1.05,1.05) translateY(-15px); }
    57%  { transform: scale(1,1)   translateY(-10px); }
    64%  { transform: scale(0.5,0.5)      translateY(0); }
    100% { transform: scale(0,0)      translateY(0); }
}
```

and apply this animation in slide_close

```
.slide_close .cs_action_trigger {
    animation: unbubble .7s 0.5;
}
```

let me know if this works